# How does history work in fish shell?

Tags: command-history, fish

I'm a bash user, starting a new job at a place where people use fish shell.

I'm looking at the `history` command which I often use in bash. When I use it in fish I get a long list of my history which I can scroll up and down on with the arrow keys.

There are no numbers like in bash and pressing enter is the same as the down key.

How can I run a past command with fish shell's `history`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[The `history` command in the fish shell](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/cmds/history.html) isn't bash-compatible, it's just displaying it in a pager (e.g. `less`).

To select an old command, you'll probably want to enter the part you remember *right into the commandline*, press up-arrow until you have found what you want and then press enter to execute.

E.g. on my system I enter `mes`, press up and `rm -I meson.build` appears (with the "mes" part highlighted). I then press enter and it executes.

Comment: But what if you don't remember the command, but read your history and find it out? E.g. “whichever command I ran immediately after that one” or “that command contained the name of a Chinese emperor but I don't remember which one”.

Comment: Thanks faho and yes @gilles another big downside is that you can't really use a double grep.

Comment: You can search the history with the usual pager command (usually '/'), or pipe it through `grep` or other commands. Like git, or systemctl, the pager is only used if the output is directly to a TTY.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this is [by design](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/2200), but you can mimic other shell's behavior with a pipe into the `nl` command (or setup an alias like `alias history="history | nl"`

However, if you were looking for numbers in order to do [history expansion](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#History-Expansion) (ex. `!123` to re-run command 123 in list), it seems that fish does not support this, but you may find some workarounds here: https://superuser.com/questions/719531/what-is-the-equivalent-of-bashs-and-in-the-fish-shell