# How can I get numbers in fish history

Tags: shell, fish

I'm using `fish` shell but the `history` command in this returns something like

```
ls
cd Downloads
ls
mkdir new_folder
```

whereas, the same thing in `zsh` would return

```
399 ls
400 cd Downloads
401 ls
402 mkdir new_folder
```

How can I get these numbers in fish too?

Comment: Similar question that may help you: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/714199/82596

Answer (score 1):

`history | cat -n` would do it.

But don't forget that if you remove lines from the history you will not remove the number (because the historyfile of fish doesn't save them).
For example: When you remove the line `cd Downloads` the 2nd `ls` will become `400`.

`zsh` on the other hand saves the numbers in `~/.zsh_history` file so here the 2nd `ls` will stay `401`

When using `fish` you might be interested `history --show-time`. It won't show the number, but it will show the time when every command was executed.

**Edit:** To answer your comment: `history | cat -n | grep 315`

But more useful: `history | cat -n | less` followed by <kbd>/</kbd>, <kbd>3</kbd>, <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>5</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
That way you can easily see the commands right before and right after that specific command by using the up/down keys.

(I added the comment-answer to the original answer because key-formatting fails in comments)

Comment: When using zsh, I sometimes use numbers to navigate through history using `grep <number>` to find the nearby commands to a particular one, say `ls` which is at `320`. So I use `history | grep 315` to check the commands typed before that. Is there a way to achieve this?